# Storm respect grouping for more than 1 stream

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have a bolt that depends on the output stream of another:

```
builder.setBolt("my-bolt", new MyBolt(), 10)
.fieldsGrouping("source-bolt-1", "stream", new Fields("f1", "f2"));
```

This works as intended an each `MyBolt` always gets the tuples that have the same `"f1", "f2"`

What I want to do now is to subscribe this bolt to a new stream, let's call it:

`.fieldsGrouping("source-bolt-2", "stream", new Fields("f1", "f2"));`

Is it possible for storm to send the tuples with the same `"f1", "f2"` for both streams?